# var/cache/apt/archives occupying huge space

Tags: cleanup, apt-cache

I am in the process of cleaning up my system. And I see a lot of space occupied by this folder `/var/cache/apt/archives` (1.5GB). Is it absolutely necessary to keep all these archives?

Comment: I have an entry in crontab that runs a script once a month. echo yourpassword | sudo -S apt-get clean. This is reasonable safe if you are the only one with physical access to your computer.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You don't need to keep them around if you don't want them. Executing a

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

will clean out the directory.

Comment: Why after I have issued this command I still can see the cached deb files in the Ubuntu Tweek tool?

Comment: @Cristiano it might be that the tool is in a partially-installed state and so apt thinks it needs to keep it.

Answer (score 47):

Seems like

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

is a better choice than

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

`autoclean` will only remove "useless" archives

From the man page:

> Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. The difference is that it only removes package files that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless.
>          This allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of control. The
>          configuration option APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being erased if it
>          is set to off.

Comment: Even if this is what I also remembered from way back - turns out, for me (on 11.04) `autoclean` did NOT remove files in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` - while `clean` did...

Comment: I'm actually seeing the opposite, `autoclean` basically emptied the directory while `clean` did nothing.

Comment: just brilliant... The first things i found so easy .. :p

Comment: No, clean is the better choice if you want to save disk space. My testing (ubuntu 18) showed _clean_ removed 18G when _autoclean_ removed little (less than 1 GB, if that)

Comment: useless archives to me are installed ones (I download only most times), by not specifying what "useless" actually means makes that option useless (pun intended :))

Comment: `autoclean` is perfect after an upgrade. It keeps current packages, but deletes old ones from the previous version. Note that you can use the `-s` (or `--simulate` or `--dry-run`) option to see what would be deleted without actually doing it.

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust settings in Synaptic package manager, menu Settings/Preferences, the Files tab. From there you can also delete the cache.

Comment: "delete downloaded packages after installation" is what I needed, thx!

Comment: "delete downloaded packages after installation" is what I needed, thx! a pity the clean button ignores our option see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300676/how-to-clean-var-cache-apt-archives-of-installed-and-deprecated-files-only

Answer (score 1):

It is better to save packages elsewhere then clean it up [Jorge Castro's process]. When you reinstall OS or a package it will not download again which save time and bandwidth. apt-get first check require packages in local storage[/var/cache/apt/archives] if does not exists then download else just do install. So you can save packages for future uses.

Comment: I doubt he will need all the 1,5Gb of updates to use on a new system!

Comment: They can be moved on a CD or other support, so they don't waste space on the local drive. This is called a '[local repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal)'.

Comment: Save packages elsewhere? Yes, that's what I've done here. I've `mv`'d the whole `/var/cache/apt/archives` to `/usr/tmp/apt-archive-cache` and set an `archives` symbolic link in `/var/cache/apt` accordingly. Since especially `audacity` likes to store temporary files in `/var`, this directory should always be taken care of so that it never runs out of space.

Answer (score 1):

If you have automatic unattended upgrades, like a Google Cloud VM has, you can today read the information in this file:

```
/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily
```

Then add and adjust a new file here:

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

The most relevant settings, I think, are these:

```
#  APT::Archives::MaxAge "0"; (old, deprecated)
#  APT::Periodic::MaxAge "0"; (new)
#  - Set maximum allowed age of a cache package file. If a cache.
#    package file is older it is deleted (0=disable)
```

and maybe even more so these two:

```
#  APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
#  - Do "apt-get autoclean" every n-days (0=disable)
#
#  APT::Periodic::CleanInterval "0";
#  - Do "apt-get clean" every n-days (0=disable)
```

I had to add the bottom two, because my VM was running out of space and the apt cache was several GBs of old junk.

I added them like this.

```
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
// Do "apt-get autoclean" every n-days (0=disable)

APT::Periodic::CleanInterval "7";
// Do "apt-get clean" every n-days (0=disable)
```

And maybe even only the last setting is necessary, as it cleans more than auto-clean does.

```
APT::Periodic::CleanInterval "7";
// Do "apt-get clean" every n-days (0=disable)
```