# Where is .deb package location after I run apt dist-upgrade on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, deb

I am using Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` in the Terminal there isn't any problem.

After that, I want to copy the .deb file in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` using Thunar file manager, but it doesn't exist.

See screenshot below:

[image]

But the `locate` command finds it:

[image]

The summary, file .deb is there in /var/cache/apt/archives/

I am confused, what’s wrong with my system?
Could you help about this problem, please?

Comment: I think this is a permissions issue. Kindly edit your question and include the result of `ll /var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: I can't add one image again, because my reputation is less of 10. I added the result of ls in my web on this link : http://feraproject.wc.lt/arsip/ls.png

Comment: It was `ll` not `ls` - kindly try again and provide a link

Comment: I'am sorry for before. This is screenshot result of ll command : http://feraproject.wc.lt/arsip/ll.png

Comment: Okay. Kindly run `sudo updatedb` then try the `locate` command again and tell me what you find. The `updatedb` commands clears the cache for the locate command.

Comment: yes. it works, the result of the locate command isn't same like before.  Parto, the locate issue is solved. But, where is the deb file from sudo apt dist-upgrade exactly ?

Comment: Did you run any other command between `sudo apt-get dist upgrade` and `locate *.deb | grep "/var/cache/"`?

Comment: Will write it as an answer then you can accept it. Let's fix the deb file issue first.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you can't find the .deb file in the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory is because it isn't there anymore.

The `locate` command finds it because locate does not look at the actual directory contents but works from a cache.

From `man locate`:

> locate  reads one or more databases prepared by updatedb(8) and writes file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs to standard output, one per line.
>
> By  default,  locate does not check whether files found in database still exist (but it does require all parent directories to exist if the database was built with --require-visibility no). locate can never report files created after the most recent update of the relevant data‐base.

To update the database cache, run this command:

```
sudo updatedb
```

> updatedb  creates  or updates a database used by locate(1).  If the database already exists, its data is reused to avoid rereading directories that have not changed.

This should sort out the `locate` command finding files that no longer exist.

---

#### EDIT

For the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` files not existing, maybe you run a clean command after running the `sudo apt-get dist upgrade` command.

Any of these commands will automatically clean out the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Source: [Cleaning out var/cache/apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space)

Comment: @Hasan Thank you too. Kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check mark to mark this question as answered. You can also up vote it by clicking the up arrow.