# Getting issue with display on Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, disk-usage, gdm, display-manager

While running docker for scraping/splash, I kept getting notification of "Empty Trash" which indicated that the disk was out of space.

After few seconds,GUI got stuck. I powered of the laptop from power button.

Then on startup, I got message like this

```
Started GNOME display manager... and deal with any system changes..p link was shut down.....
```

So I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641642/gui-does-not-start) which results in this

[ask ubuntu answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEynD.jpg)

As the image is showing, again, I also tried to clean up using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space), but got no result.

**Update**

My hard drives look like this

[Hard drive condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xdc7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following error:
`E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.`
It seems like your hard drive may be full.

You can check how much space you have available by running `df -h`

Comment: hard drive condition is added. Is there any solution to this problem.?

Comment: `/dev/sda4` is 100% used. You will need to free up hard drive space by deleting any unneeded large files. I'm not sure exactly what you were running via docker, but perhaps that created a large number of files that can be deleted.