# how to clean /var/cache/apt/archives of "installed and deprecated" files only?

Tags: apt, package-management

I use synaptic to download first and install later.
Usually I install everything but core system files, that I leave to install later.
Synaptic button "delete cached package files" ignores the fact of many files not being installed yet.
By deprecated I mean older version of downloaded packages.
I have already tried `apt-get autoclean` and it is not what I need (it cleaned nothing actually...). clean option is also useless, it cleaned everything!

Can it be done with some simple command or I have to use some script to compare installed VS downloaded/old versions?

[var/cache/apt/archives occupying huge space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65549/var-cache-apt-archives-occupying-huge-space) didn't help

I need to do it that way because of: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/624845/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-the-same-lvm-mirror-leg-only-to-update-system-core

Btw, now, for installed ones I am using:
`apt list --installed |sed -r 's"(.*)/.* (.*) (.*) .*"\1_\2_\3.deb"' |while read strFile;do strFile="`echo "$strFile" |sed -r 's":"%3a"'`";if [[ -f "$strFile" ]];then sudo rm -v $strFile;fi;done`

Comment: Look at apt's `autoclean`. See `man apt-get`. Alternately, make a very minor change to your workflow: Clean your cache right after you finish installing all those core system updates.

Comment: oh sorry, I have already tried `apt-get autoclean` and it is not what I need (it cleaned nothing actually...). clean option is also useless, it cleaned everything! Yep I enabled synaptic option but it will only work for new files not old ones.

Comment: If autoclean "cleaned nothing", then you don't seem to have any obsolete packages in your cache. That implies that you might be down the mistaken path of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Edit your question to clearly explain the actual problem you encounter that leads you to believe cleaning out the apt cache is a desirable solution.

Comment: @user535733 I do have already installed for ex.: fluid-soundfont-gm_3.1-5.1_all.deb but autoclean did NOT clean it... My question is also about installed packages, not only old ones.

Comment: Correct: `fluid-soundfont-gm_3.1-5.1_all.deb` is ineligible for autoclean. It's the latest version; not obsolete, not "deprecated". You can `clean` it: `sudo apt clean <package_name>...but that leads you down the path of scripting a custom solution. Are you saying that your apt cache is simply too large? (how large is it?)

Comment: it has 1GB and 1123 files, the only way I would have patience dealing with it would be thru a script :). My root has only 15GB and I need every 0.1GB I can recover and that cache is in the way... :/

Comment: for installed I am using this: `apt list --installed |sed -r 's"(.*)/.* (.*) (.*) .*"\1_\2_\3.deb"' |while read strFile;do if [[ -f "$strFile" ]];then sudo rm -v "$strFile";fi;done`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool (apt-deepclean) to manage this for us.  It's available on [github](https://github.com/bfccomputing/apt-deepclean).

I run it once a day out of a cronjob.  Our archives were over 20GB at one point!

Comment: Requires Perl module AptPkg, which is not present on Linux system by default and must be installed using `sudo apt-get install libapt-pkg-perl`.